# Convert PDF to HTML using pdf2dom in a JAVA app - any ways to simplify the output?

Tags: java, html, apache, pdf, pdfbox

I'm working on a task to convert PDF files to HTML inside a JAVA app.

After several attempts, I used [Pdf2Dom](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/pdf2dom/) (based on Apache PDFBox) which behaved the best from all the **free** solutions.

The problem is that the output is unnecessarily complicated

***Example***: a pdf with one simple line of text in the simplest possible format:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Will generate a html output consisting in **one** *< div ...>* **element for each word in the text**, something like below:

```
<div class="p" id="p0" style="top:85.44616pt;left:62.4pt;line-height:11.1054pt;font-family:Arial;font-size:9.0pt;width:17.310478pt;">The</div>
<div class="p" id="p1" sty
.........
.........                                                                                                                       928pt;">the</div>
<div class="p" id="p7" style="top:85.44616pt;left:222.8357pt;line-height:11.1054pt;font-family:Arial;font-size:9.0pt;width:17.798523pt;">lazy</div>
<div class="p" id="p8" style="top:85.44616pt;left:243.32341pt;line-height:11.1054pt;font-family:Arial;font-size:9.0pt;width:19.451889pt;">dog.</div>
```

***The obvious question***: are there any possibilities to fine-tune the *"org.fit.pdfdom.PDFDomTree"* that does the parsing and conversion and at least partially get rid of the unneeded formatting ?

Thank you.

Comment: I know it's been 3 years, but if there is any update on this post I would be very interested